# How to allow one django project to have different application notification settings

Tags: python, django, django-push-notifications

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
'FCM_API_KEY': '[key]',
"FCM_ERROR_TIMEOUT": 1800,
'APNS_CERTIFICATE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "[.pem]"),
"APNS_USE_SANDBOX": "api.development.push.apple.com",
"UPDATE_ON_DUPLICATE_REG_ID": True,
"APNS_USE_SANDBOX":True
}
```

Above setting declared two times within two different apps

I have one Django project but this project support two mobile different application one is a shop owner and one is a customer this 2 apps different server key and both have to send notifications so need two declared two key so how can possible

Comment: Need more information, It's unclear what you need.

Comment: @VineethSai I have one Django project but this project support two mobile different application one is a shop owner and one is a customer
this 2 apps different server key and both have to send notifications so need two declared two key so how can possible

Comment: Add this to the question it will be easy to find.